# Test Class Deployment Failure duplicate value found <unknown> duplicates

Tags: deployment, unit-test

When we are trying to deploy a test class, We are seeing the following error on many test classes

```
duplicate value found <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
```

Everything else is deployed without any issues. This test class alone is causing problems for us.

We are facing issue with this test class alone. We have gone through below solution. But, we couldn't find any history tracking on the objects the insertions are failing.

[Object Deploy fails with: "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/object-deploy-fails-with-duplicate-value-found-unknown-duplicates-value-on)

Please let us know if you need more info.

Comment: The issue is fixed now. The errors are completely misleading. In test class we found that a an update statement is violating unique constraint.

Comment: It would be great if you posted your answer below and marked it as the correct answer. This is good information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed now. The errors are completely misleading. In test class we found that a an update statement is violating unique constraint