# <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>

Tags: deployment, error, ant, duplicate-management

As part of an ant deployment, to recently cleaned Org, I get the following:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  objects/CustomObject__c.object (CustomObject__c.SomeQueue) -- Warning: Added entity: CustomObject__c support on queue: SomeQueue (line 1334, column 16)
2.  layouts/CustomObject__c-One Layout.layout -- Error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
3.  layouts/CustomObject__c-Another Layout.layout -- Error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
```

The first seems to be due to Salesforce's own circular logic; an object has a listview based on a queue and a queue is linked to an object. I just a warning so I guess its OK?

The other two I have no idea how to debug.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue? I've tried turning trackFeedHistory off as suggested [here.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/object-deploy-fails-with-duplicate-value-found-unknown-duplicates-value-on)

Comment: Are there fields with the same name ? (including deleted fields which are still in the destination org).

Comment: There do not appear to be any duplicate fields. The object can be deployed fine. Metadata are deleted with destructivechanges.xml and purgeondelete='true'.

Comment: Powlo were you able to solve this (first warning regarding queue)? If so, would you mind posting your solution?

Comment: @SwisherSweet My only advice would be to avoid packaging queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editor's Note:** This issue has been [resolved in Winter 19](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5hTAAS)

---

The `Error: duplicate value found` error seems to be a bug, related to deploying two inter-related objects with history tracking. See here:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5hTAAS

Suggested workaround is splitting deployment into stages