# Warning: Added entity: My_Custom_Object__c support on queue: MyQueue

Tags: list-view, migration-tool, queue, deployment

I'm using the Salesforce Migration Tool (Ant) to migrate a custom object. I am using the migration tool to pull the custom object down then deploy it. The package.xml is very simply... just trying to deploy one custom object and related queues at this time.

While doing so, I'm getting this error:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  objects/My_Custom_Object__c.object (My_Custom_Object__c.My_View) -- Warning: Added entity: My_Custom_Object__c support on queue: MyQueue (line 670, column 16)
```

This problem is similar to [the problem powlo had](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50394/unknown-duplicates-value-on-record-with-id-unknown) (first part only), which doesn't have an answer.

There are several errors just like this one that is preventing my code from deploying. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are all the messages warnings? Does MyQueue correspond to a [Custom Object Queue](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=queues_overview.htm) on My_Custom_Object__c?

Comment: Daniel, MyQueue is a queue related to My_Custom_Object__c. There is no "My Object Queue"

Comment: So the Custom Object, the Queue and the View are all part of the same deploy? Could you try splitting out the Custom Object and then deploying the Queue and View in a subsequent deploy?

Comment: Daniel, thanks so much. Removing the views allowed me to deploy the object. Do you want to post as answer so you get credit?

Comment: Did the custom object and queue deployed OK together? Was it just the view for the queue then?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in a big package...

Removing the Queues from the package proved complicated as there were quite a few references and I was moving from one error to another.

Based on the previous comments, I ended-up deploying in 2 stages:

1) Deploy an "empty shell" made of bare bone objects only:

1.1) Backup the "src" folder into "src-backup"

1.2) Delete all sub-folders in "src" other than "objects"

1.3) Edit  package.xml to only keep a single component type = CustomObject

1.4) Edit all "objects/*.object" xml files to only keep the information entered at time of creation of the object. Example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <allowInChatterGroups>true</allowInChatterGroups>
    <compactLayoutAssignment>SYSTEM</compactLayoutAssignment>
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
    <description>MyObject is used to do this and that...</description>
    <enableActivities>true</enableActivities>
    <enableBulkApi>true</enableBulkApi>
    <enableFeeds>true</enableFeeds>
    <enableHistory>true</enableHistory>
    <enableReports>true</enableReports>
    <enableSharing>true</enableSharing>
    <enableStreamingApi>true</enableStreamingApi>
    <externalSharingModel>ReadWrite</externalSharingModel>
    <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
    <nameField>
        <displayFormat>MyObj-{000000000}</displayFormat>
        <label>My Object ID</label>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>AutoNumber</type>
    </nameField>
    <label>My Object</label>
    <pluralLabel>My Objects</pluralLabel>
    <recordTypeTrackFeedHistory>true</recordTypeTrackFeedHistory>
    <recordTypeTrackHistory>false</recordTypeTrackHistory>
</CustomObject>
```

2) Re-Deploy the original package

2.1) Delete the "src" folder

2.2) Rename "src-backup" folder to "src"

2.3) Run a Deploy again.

Should be working now!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error and solved it by creating basic object in salesforce manually (if your object has private, public read only security setting then you have to do that manually first) then deployed the package. Worked out successfully without any error.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, there appears to be a dependency between the Custom Object definition, its associated Queue, and the View.

Try splitting the the definition of the Custom Object from its dependencies and deploying it first. Then deploy the queue and view separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning message and not the error. In your build xml make the "Ignore Warnings" flag to false and deploy.