# Developer Script Exception Duplicate Values Found

Tags: apex

**Error:**

> Developer script exception from . : ConsumerBookingCreate : ConsumerBookingCreate: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: unknown duplicates value on record with id: 0011600001oyhaS: [] Class.ConsumerBookingCreateHelper.createBooking: line 57, column 1 Trigger.ConsumerBookingCreate: line 2, column 1

Getting the error at these lines:

```
if ( insertAccountList != null )
    {
        System.debug('About to insert accounts. ' + insertAccountList);
        insert insertAccountList;
        System.debug('AFTER insert of person accounts');
    }
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger ConsumerBookingCreate on Case (after insert) {
   ConsumerBookingCreateHelper.createBooking(trigger.new);
}
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public with sharing class ConsumerBookingCreateHelper {

public static void createBooking(List<case> cases){     
    List<account> insertAccountList = new List<account>();
    List<booking__c> insertBookingList = new List<booking__c>();
    Map<Id, Account> caseToAccountMap = new Map<Id, Account>() ;
    Set<String> facilityIds = new Set<String>();
    Map<String, Facility__c> facilityMap = new Map<String, Facility__c>();
    Set<Decimal> userIds = new Set<Decimal>();
    Map<Decimal, User> userMap = new Map<Decimal, User>();
    
    RecordType persRecordType;
    List<RecordType> persRecordTypes = [ select Id, Name, DeveloperName from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Account' and IsPersonType = true ];
    
    if ( persRecordTypes != null && persRecordTypes.size() > 0 )
    {
        persRecordType = persRecordTypes[0];        
    }
    else
    {
        persRecordType = new RecordType(id='012G00000012BAJ');
    }
    
    for(Case c : cases) {
        if (c.Phantom_Case__c == true && c.Origin == 'Web') {
            Account newA = new Account();
            if (c.Last_Name_WTC__c != null) {
                newA.LastName = c.Last_Name_WTC__c;
            } else {
                newA.LastName='No Last Name';
            }
            newA.RecordTypeId = persRecordType.Id;
            newA.RecordTypeId = '012G00000012BAJ';
            newA.FirstName = c.First_Name_WTC__c;
            newA.LastName = c.Last_Name_WTC__c;
            newA.Phone = c.SuppliedPhone;
            newA.Alternate_Phone__c = c.Alternate_Phone_WTC__c;
            newA.PersonEmail = c.SuppliedEmail;
            newA.Partner_ID__c = c.Partner_WTC__c;
            newA.Partner_Website__c = c.Partner_Website__c;
            newA.Original_Booking_Case__c = c.Id;
            newA.Consumer_Id__c = c.Consumer_Id_WTC__c;
            
            insertAccountList.add(newA);    
            
            // set up the facility Ids
            facilityIds.add( c.facility_external_id_WTC__c );        
            
            // set up the user Ids
            userIds.add( c.SpareFoot_Booking_Agent_Id_WTC__c );
        }   
    }
    System.debug('Testing for accounts.') ;  
    if ( insertAccountList != null )
    {
        System.debug('About to insert accounts. ' + insertAccountList);
        insert insertAccountList;
        System.debug('AFTER insert of person accounts');
    }
    
    // get the facility Ids
    if ( facilityIds != null && facilityIds.size() > 0 )
    {
        List<Facility__c> facilities = [SELECT id, name, Facility_Id__c, Account__r.Id FROM Facility__c WHERE Facility_Id__c IN : facilityIds ];
        if ( facilities != null && facilities.size() > 0 )
        {
            for ( Facility__c f : facilities )
            {
                facilityMap.put( f.Facility_Id__c, f );
            }
        }
    }
    
    // get the user Ids
    if ( userIds != null && userIds.size() > 0 )
    {
        List<User> users = [SELECT id, name, Booking_Agent_Id__c FROM User WHERE Booking_Agent_Id__c IN : userIds ];
        if ( users != null && users.size() > 0 )
        {
            for ( User u : users )
            {
                userMap.put( u.Booking_Agent_Id__c, u );
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

See [How to debug the mysterious "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>" error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79799/how-to-debug-the-mysterious-duplicate-value-found-unknown-duplicates-value-o) for a helpful discussion.

In short, it sounds like one of your `Account` fields is defined as unique.  You're trying to insert a non-unique field value on one or more of your `Account`s in `insertAccountList`, hence the error.  You can start by going through your Account fields and looking to find which of them should be unique.

It looks like you're also mistakenly setting `newA.LastName` and `newA.RecordTypeId` twice each within your `createBooking()` method, so I'd double-check your entire code for similar issues you may be overlooking.