# What is the purpose of each folder (module) in the Package Directory in sfdx-falcon project?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-falcon

I am working on an sfdx project based on the sfdx-falcon template. I studied all available materials that I could find:

1. [SFDX-Falcon Project Template](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/sfdx-falcon-template)
2. [Salesforce DX 201 - Advanced Implementation for ISVs](https://www.slideshare.net/VivekMChawla/salesforce-dx-201-advanced-implementation-for-isvs)
3. [Two SFDX project folder structure questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204998/two-sfdx-project-folder-structure-questions)

Generally it's clear how to work with a falcon project. However, when it comes to details, I am confused with the purpose of certain folders (modules), or where to put some components (e.g. pages, applications, flexipages etc.) To my bitter disappointment I couldn't find reasonable explanation so far.

### Question 1

For example, in DX Custom Metadata Types are stored in the `customMetadata` folder, and it is confusing when I see `customMetadata` and `customMetadataTypes` folders in the Schema folder. So what purpose does each of these two folders serve in the Schema folder?

### Question 2

I have a custom application (.app-meta.xml) in the `applications` folder. Where should I put my apps: somewhere in the `main` module or create a `feature` module for this?

Answer (score 3):

**Answer 1**
CustomMetadataTypes and CustomMetadata are 2 different metadata representation that is why they are stored in 2 different directory. CustomMetadataTypes can be considered as a custom metadata shape like sObjects being shape of your records. However CustomMetadata is the input for that shape.

In other words CustomMetadataTypes are special object types and CustomMetadata is a special type of record.

**Answer 2**
That depends on how you manage your metadata structure if your application contains only a specific feature related items and no dependency to any other metadata apart from your default and the subjected feature then you can store the app in your feature directory.