# Version (and keep) source of dependant Unlocked package in seperate folder

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, scratch-org, unlocked-package, 2gp-ama

As I [detail here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310545/) I am going to install the external libraries I use when building Managed Packages in scratch orgs using dependencies in the `sfdx-project.json` being installed in an scratc-org installation script like this:

```
{
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
    "packageDirectories": [{
        "path": "force-app",
        "versionNumber": "1.1.0.NEXT",
        "package": "myManagedPackage",
        "dependencies": [{
            "package": "fflib@LATEST",
        }]
    }],
    "packageAliases": {
        "fflib": "0Ho4A000000fxXpSAI",
        "fflib@LATEST": "04t4A000000onRXQAI",
    }
}
```

How can I make sure the fflib metadata when pulled from org to local source (and later my VCS) is stored in a seperate `force-app` subfolder like:

- `force-app/default` for my app
- `force-app/fflib` for the content of the external library

Comment: Packages you install should not trigger changes when using push/pull (though they will for retrieve/deploy).

Comment: So you mean the metadata will not end up in my VCS and then also not be pushed in to my packaging org later when I run my deploy metadata script? :-(

Comment: Right. If you use `sfdx force:package:install`, those changes are not tracked, so `force:source:pull` won't detect those changes. I've discovered this to my annoyance when I was trying to fix my repo using my existing unlocked packages.

Comment: I actually like it, then I just need to make sure those get installed in tha Packaging org as well and become "magically" part of my package. And then the namespace thing from my other question becomes and even hotter topic.

Comment: The components in the dependencies need to have `@namespaceAccessible` in order to use them in the same namespace, but other than that, nothing special is necessary.

Comment: You are getting me wrong. I will installed an Unlocked version of the fflib in my scratch org which my code will rely on.