# Source format structure questions

Tags: salesforcedx

I have gone through [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204998/two-sfdx-project-folder-structure-questions) post which covers few aspects of source format. But I still have few questions as follows.

Assuming this is the structure,

```
force-app -------> Level 1 (package)
  main ----------> Level 2  
    default -----> Level 3
      classes ---> Level 4 (components folder)
      lwc
      aura
      ...
```

1. Level 1 is called package (as it is listed under packageDirectories node in project json). Level 4 is called components folder as naming of it comes from what components it holds. What is Level 2 and Level 3 called? Is there a standard naming convention? If there is none provided by Salesforce is there an accepted names for these?
2. Is it always required to have Level 2/3? It is not documented anywhere if Level 2/3 are required. Is it okay to expect to have Level 1/2/3 if we are building some tool to deal with metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The middle layers don't have names, that I've found, nor a description of how it should work. I've always used a "feature/subfeature" notation, such as "sales/opportunities", "support/cases", or "utils/apex". Also, it's notable that you can have arbitrarily deep nested folders, limited only by your file system's maximum file path/file name limitations.

The level 2/3 folders are **not** required. You can just as easily have `project/classes/Class1.cls` or `project/marketing/campaigns/classes/utils/CampaignTriggerHandler.cls`.

The SFDX system uses the concept of what I call "magic folders." Basically, every type of metadata has a specific folder name, and within that folder name, a certain structure is expected. These rules differ between data types. Failure to observe these rules result in deployment errors.

For example, you can have `project/sales/objects/Opportunity`, but not `project/objects/sales/Opportunity`. This is because `objects` expects one folder per `CustomObject`, with a specific structure inside. However, you can have `project/sales/classes/utils/OpportunityTriggerHandler.cls`, because the `classes` folder automatically collapses the folders inside.

You also can't do something like `project/classes/lwc/myLwcComponent`, because once `classes` is encountered, everything inside there must be an Apex class. Similarly, `project/lwc/sales/lwc/myComponent` won't work as you expect, as it will create a component called `sales`, rather than `myComponent`. Again, as soon as SFDX finds a magic folder, the rules change depending on the folder encountered.

You'll need to know the names of all the folders, and if they support nested directories or not. Most folders do *not* support this, with the two main exceptions being `triggers` and `classes`. It's not expected that there will be four levels, there may be 2 levels or 20, or anything inbetween.

Comment: Thank you for the info @sfdcfox. Dx format is too flexible in this regard to the point that it adds so much complexity without much gain. For our product, we will go with three levels, package/feature/subfeature and hope that some restriction in the structure reduces some complexity. Also hope that ecosystem understands these issues and starts to coalesce around 3 levels and naming.

Comment: I think it fair to say that if a packageDirectory is marked as default, pulling new metadata from an org will drop it in "main/default/..." within that "default" directory. I haven't seen a way to prevent this. Obviously you can then move the files elsewhere and set version control to never add "main/default" stuff.