# What is the file order for an sfdx force:source:push (and why is a sfdx force:source:push silently failing)?

Tags: salesforcedx, gack

I get a failure when doing a `sfdx force:source:push` (sfdx-cli/7.170.0) with no additional helpful information (in the console or in $HOME/.sf/sf.log) but always at this point:

```
DEPLOY PROGRESS | █████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 278/2164 Components
DEPLOY PROGRESS | █████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 278/2164 Components
DEPLOY PROGRESS | █████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 278/2164 Components
DEPLOY PROGRESS | ██████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 335/2164 Components
DEPLOY PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 0/0 Components
Updating source tracking... done
```

so understanding how the components are ordered would allow me to examine components 336, 337, 338 etc more carefully than the others and perhaps identify the problem.

I do get a gack that I could get Salesforce support to look at. And given that `sfdx force:source:deploy` works with no problem, this may be an `sfdx` bug.

But what is the file order used for push?

**PS**

If the file order is the one reported after a `sfdx force:source:deploy` runs, then that corresponds in my case to about half way through the classes and at that point there are no recent changes in my files.

**PPS**

I did create a support request and got this "received two objects that are exactly the same" information; I will ask if there is any evidence of which components were being handled at the time in the log before this point.

``````
gslog`20221007141045.602`4ljDhuyn1fxA-vX2-swQI-`8609`0`0`0`````6f8a8dcab5a8cb7d`8037392386766719869``0`fe:034`238.18.34```00D5C0000009GXn`0055C000004bCrr``486193339-46120`208639346`default-racNode-3--MqFrameworkBaseHandler-session(490732933)-processor-threadId-8609````SEVERE``common.api.soap.metadata.core.deploy.AbstractFileBasedMetadataWorker`handleThrowable
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: bulkDml: received two objects that are exactly the same (==) at common.udd.object.BulkDml.validateEntityObjects(BulkDml.java:112)


"`java.lang.IllegalStateException: bulkDml: received two objects that are exactly the same (==) "
``````

Comment: Is this all from a single sfdx project directory? Have you cleared the local tracking data (in `.sfdx` and/or `.sf`) and done a forced push?

Comment: Hi @PhilW, It is failing both in a CI new checkout/push, and running locally. Changing to a deploy both work. Hence the thought that this project is hitting an sfdx bug.

Comment: Did you try clearing the tracking state for the specific org you are targeting?

Comment: I didn't in that the CI starts from scratch every time so is a clean start.

Comment: But uses the same org? If "starting from scratch", why not actually start literally from scratch (org creation)?! :D

Comment: Hi @PhilW, Our CI checks out, creates a scratch org and deploys to that, runs the tests, then deletes the scratch org.

Comment: OK, I understand better now. You have the problem regardless of the org itself, and only with push, not deploy. Sorry, I didn't get the scenario quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the gack detail from Salesforce that the push error originated from:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: bulkDml: received two objects that are exactly the same (==)

but no specific component name, the question became "how can you have such a situation"?

With a single source code root i.e. only the `force-app/main/default` I don't think you can. But this project has two source code roots, and doing a pull from the org I had pulled a duplicate copy of a field that was in the second root into the `force-app/main/default` root. (Personally I favour the KISS one root approach but I didn't create this project.)

Luckily the second source code root had only a small amount of content so I found the duplicate by manual means. Otherwise I would have had to create a script to look for duplicates. Hopefully Salesforce will improve the handling of this case in the future so that the duplicate component name is passed back through SFDX and an error that took me several days to figure out will be made quick to identify.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how this command works. It is similar to the MDAPI in that regards; all the contents are packaged up, sent to the server for validation, then enters a polling loop to check the status of the deploy with [DeployResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deployresult.htm). All it's really doing is showing you `numberComponentsDeployed` / `numberComponentsTotal`. In other words, it doesn't know about the specific order of files processed. You can check Setup > Monitoring > Deployment Status to try and get additional information regarding the deployment, and you may also have extra information in `~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` or `%USERHOME%/.sfdx/sfdx.log`, depending on your OS and shell.

Comment: No useful information in the Deployment Status just a gack code. Zero length sfdx.log and just this opaque error in sf.log `{"name":"sf","hostname":"keiths-mbp.lan","pid":59652,"log":"Push","level":50,"msg":"[\n  '\\x1B[1mERROR running force:source:push: \\x1B[22m',\n  '\\x1B[31mPush failed.\\x1B[39m'\n]","time":"2022-10-05T17:32:25.438Z","v":0}`. Hence clutching at straws.

Comment: A CI new checkout/push, and a local checkout/push both fail. Changing to a deploy both work. Hence the thought that this specific project is hitting an sfdx bug related to the push version tracking.

Comment: @KeithC What's the gack? That might be useful in the right hands.

Comment: One example: `2024855175-46760 (208639346)`.