# Deploy lightning web component is getting failed with error - "--json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1"

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I am trying to deploy a lightning web component to the org using vs-code but getting the error.

```
Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

10:09:14.43 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath d:\Aakriti\Projects\LWC\LWCLearning\force-app\main\default\lwc --json --loglevel fatal
10:09:25.813 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath d:\Aakriti\Projects\LWC\LWCLearning\force-app\main\default\lwc --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1
```

Earlier I was able to deploy components successfully but after updating vs-code, I am getting this error. I am not sure what is the issue. Can anyone please let me know how can I resolve this.

I am using api-version '45'.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if the error message is limited to What you have posted in your question? Check if you are getting anything else?

Comment: @sanketkumar, No I am not getting anything else. It is not specifying the exact error message.

Comment: Is this a sandbox, developer org or production org? `sfdx force:source:deploy ` is still in beta and is not available on production orgs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm

Answer (score 20):

I was also facing the same error but did not find anything here. If your deployment is failing, so you need to go to  your developer org, setup --> Deployment Status <s>Settings</s>

Here you will find the error details. Mine was failing coz I had already one lightning component by "HelloWorld", so I had to delete it.

You might face some other error here. So please check and then try.

Comment: thank you, with your help I can at least see the actual error. BTW it is Setup > Deployment Status and not Deployment Settings.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thats the issue but i was unable to delete the component so created a new component with a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Try the execute the command from Terminal window of VS Code, by putting 'trace' log level.
Generally, you can copy the command from the output window.
Eg.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath "c:\Users\Ross\Documents\Personal Practice Orgs\gungunaDev\force-app\main\default\lwc\customPathUiLwc" --json --loglevel trace
```

On the terminal window, after running the command you get the detailed errors.
In my case, I was having a different name for my folder and my Component files.

I got the message as below. Which said that you 'Cannot find Lightning Component Bundle'.
After looking at the error I realized that somehow I changed the name of the folder but not the files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. There is no specific error message after the '--json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1'

To have a more specific error message, use Salesforce CLI terminal: 
"sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath \force-app"

This gives an error of: 
"MissingMessageError: Missing message mdapi_deploy"

If we have the same problem, Uninstalling and installing Salesforce CLI should fix the problem