# Contact deletion error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>

Tags: contact, duplicate-management, contact-deletion

As the title states, I get this error message when attempting to delete certain contacts:
duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id:

There are questions/google search results for this error message, including [this stackoverflow question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79799/how-to-debug-the-mysterious-duplicate-value-found-unknown-duplicates-value-o)

However, after reviewing those results, I have been unable to relate them to my situation.

Why would *deleting* a record cause a duplicate error?

Comment: Maybe because of a trigger? Have you checked the debug logs?

Comment: Did you find something in your debug logs ?

Comment: @sfdcfox @​elijah I setup debug logs and tried to delete again. The debug logs are essentially blank, containing only metadata about the debug levels, my user, and the date/time. 

The debug levels are: APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,FINEST;CALLOUT,FINER;DB,FINEST;NBA,NONE;SYSTEM,FINE;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,FINE;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO